# JAVA array concatenation from two different arrays

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation

How to concatenate each and every number from 2 arrays and then give the output individually of the new no. formed?

Example:

```
arr1[1,2,3] 
arr2[2,3,5] 
output: [12,13,15,22,23,25,32,33,33,35]
```

Comment: Use two loops. One nested inside the other. Each loop, loops over one of the arrays. In the inner loop u push the concatenation of the element from  each array on to a new array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way of doing it that doesn't involve using `String`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] arr2 = { 2, 3, 5 };
    int[] arr = concat(arr1, arr2);     
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}

static int[] concat(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int[] arr = new int[arr1.length * arr2.length];
    for (int n2 : arr2)
    {
        int pow10 = (int) Math.pow(10, nDigits(n2));
        for (int n1 : arr1)
        {
            arr[i++] = n1 * pow10 + n2;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

static int nDigits(int n)
{
    return (n == 0) ? 1 : 1 + (int) Math.log10(n);
}
```

Output:

```
[12, 22, 32, 13, 23, 33, 15, 25, 35]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop inside of a `for` loop. Then concatenate the item from `arr` and the item from `arr2`. I used an `ArrayList` but you could use a normal array if you know the resultant length of the array.

```
    String[] arr = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
    String[] arr2 = new String[]{"2", "3", "5"};
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            res.add(arr[i] + arr2[j]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(res.toString());
```

The result is:

```
[12, 13, 15, 22, 23, 25, 32, 33, 35]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to display the contents of the two array in the form you have given above you can always try doing this instead of concatinating it.

```
public class ArrayQuestion {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3};
    int arr2[] = {2,3,5};
    for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<arr2.length;j++) {
            System.out.print(arr1[i]);
            System.out.print(arr2[j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Output :
`12
13
15
22
23
25
32
33
35`

Comment: no actually i have to check by concatineting those 2 nos. wether the new number formed are even or not,so i will have to con. them.